# Tile collision detection

Tags: java, 2d, lwjgl, tilemap, platformer

Right. So I was making this simple game. The player is two tiles wide, and four tiles high. My current code is really buggy (it was better before my rewrite)

Here it is:

```
    float newx = position.x + velocity.x;
    float newy = position.y + velocity.y;

    int tx = (int) newx;
    int ty = (int) newy;

    Tile tile = WorldHandler.currentWorld.getTile(tx, ty);
    Tile ground = WorldHandler.currentWorld.getTile((int) position.x, (int) position.y-1);

    if (tile.type == 0) {
        position.x = newx;
        position.y = newy;
    }
    if (ground.type != 0) {
        grounded = true;
        //position.y = Math.round(position.y);
    }       

    if (grounded) {
        velocity.x = 0.0f;
        velocity.y = 0.0f;
        //position.y = Math.round(position.y);
    } else {
        velocity.x = velocity.x * (1.0f - Math.min(0.1f, 1.0f));
        velocity.y += 0.0f;
    }
```

it basically uses the indices for performance.

But I need a decent collision detection system that wouldn't be painful to implement, would AARBs be of use here? Also, the game loop is a tick based one, it runs at 30 ticks/s.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what shape your tiles are. If they are all rectangles, just use the *contains* method. Check for collisions in your *running* or *present* methods (whichever to call the ongoing loop).

If you have different shaped tiles, you could try using methods like the following:

```
public static boolean overlapCircles(MyCircle c1, MyCircle c2) {
    float distance = c1.center.distSquared(c2.center);
    float radiusSum = c1.radius + c2.radius;
    return distance <= radiusSum * radiusSum;
}

public static boolean overlapRectangles(MyRect r1, MyRect r2) {
    if(r1.lowerLeft.x < r2.lowerLeft.x + r2.width &&
            r1.lowerLeft.x + r1.width > r2.lowerLeft.x &&
            r1.lowerLeft.y < r2.lowerLeft.y + r2.height &&
            r1.lowerLeft.y + r1.height > r2.lowerLeft.y)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public static boolean overlapCircleRectangle(MyCircle c, MyRect r) {
    float closestX = c.center.x;
    float closestY = c.center.y;
    Log.i("in overlap tester", "");

    if(c.center.x < r.lowerLeft.x){
        closestX = r.lowerLeft.x;
        Log.i("in x", "");
    }
    else if(c.center.x > r.lowerLeft.x + r.width){
        closestX = r.lowerLeft.x + r.width;
    }

    if(c.center.y < r.lowerLeft.y){
        closestY = r.lowerLeft.y;
    }
    else if(c.center.y > r.lowerLeft.y + r.height){
        closestY = r.lowerLeft.y + r.height;
    }

    return c.center.distSquared(closestX, closestY) < c.radius * c.radius;
}
```

In the main part of the game I called them using:

```
private boolean collideWithEnemy() {
    boolean hit = false;
    MyCircle playerCir = new MyCircle(player.pPos[0], player.pPos[1], 5);
    MyCircle en1Cir = new MyCircle(en1.pos[0], en1.pos[1], 10);
    hit = OverlapTester.overlapCircles(playerCir, en1Cir);

    //If the hit was true for en1 without the if it would turn it false.
    if (!hit) {
        MyCircle en2Cir = new MyCircle(en2.pos[0], en2.pos[1], 10);
        hit = OverlapTester.overlapCircles(playerCir, en2Cir);
        if(!hit) {
            MyRect en3Rect = new MyRect(en3.pos[0], en3.pos[1], 20, 20);
            hit = OverlapTester.overlapCircleRectangle(playerCir, en3Rect);
            if(hit) {
                en3.pos[0] = -20;
            }
        }
    }
    return hit;
}
```

Comment: Nice! The rectangle method is what I need.